# Repository Pattern EF Core Update method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a question about using the Repository Pattern and Unit of Work pattern in a MVC Web Application with Entity Framework Core.

I am currently implementing the update functionality in the controller. Now, at this point I am not sure what the best way is to update the entity.  I have watched some videos where they said that an Update method should not be present in a repository like this:

```cs
public T Update(T entity)
{
  DbSet.Attach(entity);
  var entry = Context.Entry(entity);
  entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
}
```

So that means that I will have to do it like this in the controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Edit(int id, [Bind("NeighbourhoodGroup,Neighbourhood,NeighbourhoodId")] Neighbourhoods neighbourhoods)
{
  var neighbourhoodsFound = unitOfWork.Neighbourhoods.Get(id);
  neighbourhoodsFound.Neighbourhood = neighbourhoods.Neighbourhood;
  neighbourhoodsFound.NeighbourhoodGroup = neighbourhoods.NeighbourhoodGroup;
}
```

However, that means that I will have to do this in all controllers, even if the object has alot of Properties?

I hope someone can give me some advice on what the best approach would be.

Comment: You don't need an Update method. You don't need a repository either. You're breaking EF Core and trying to re-implement what's already implemented. BTW that `update` method doesn't update anything, it only attaches a detached entity in the modified state. You *do* need to attach a new entity.

Comment: Check [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) Gunnar Peipman collected all the problems with those generic repositories in a single article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your repository you can have the update functionality as simple as this:

```
public void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entity);
        ApplicationContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

While in the controller or from wherever you prefer to do your update you can get the entity preferably by id, modify all the properties that you want to modify on entity, call the the Update method from the repository which is going to set its state to modified and finally call the Save or SaveAsync method on the EF context. Your EF context should be exposed in your UnitOfWork.

For more detailed explanation you can see this post, it will be very helpful. [EF Repository Pattern](https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part4/#repository)

Comment: The EF context *is* the Unit Of Work. A DbSet *is* the "generic" repository.  The generic repository shown in that article is an antipattern. Check [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). Gunnar Peipman collected all the problems with generic repositories in one article so we don't have to repeat them

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see the problem in having `Update` method in repository. It's OK. It's more complex to read data from repository based on criteria. here you can check an example from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core).
2. Controller isn't a good place to describe your business cases: do some business logic then save to repository etc. Consider [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) as a way to describe particular business case instead of putting it into controller.

Also it's useful to read about [clean architecture](https://github.com/MaximTkachenko/CleanArchitecture).

Comment: It's definitely not OK. Having a *generic repository* like that is a very bad idea in the first place. The article you link to doesn't show a generic repository, it shows a very specific repository that only adds functionality not already provided by EF itself

Comment: Check [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) for a list of problems caused by generic repositories. With those generic repositories you lose UoW, no cost transactions, batched updates and impose a low-level abstraction on top of a higher-level one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I believe generic repositories can work OK for some types of applications. Yes, you should commit changes in the end of business transaction. In case of web application you can do it in the end of request. But it's not directly connected to repository. It's more about lifetime management of dbcontext.

Comment: Read the article. You don't need that transaction *at all*. That's what `SaveChanges` is for, and why DbContext *is* a UoW. It's **because** of generic repositories that now you need an extra long-lived transaction around the entire request. Worse, Transaction-Per-Request *never* meant *Database* transaction per request. It's a term introduced for J2EE applications more than 10 years ago, when ORMs were in their infancy, and referred to *J2EE container* transactions. They aren't needed with modern ORMs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I read the article before writing my previous comment. I wrote about business transaction not db transaction. In case of `LasteDbContext` you still need to call `BeginTransaction` and `Commit` \ `Rollback`. So no magic or silver bullet here. And you still should be careful with `LasteDbContext` lifetime.

Comment: Generic repositories are trying to be silver bullets. And what you refer to is an example of why you *don't* need a generic repository, and how easy it is to use transactions if you really need them. Which, you normally don't, because `SaveChanges` already uses transactions.

Comment: As for the repo's lifetime, it's the `using` block it's defined in. In DI scenarios, if and only if there's an appropriate scope, can we leave lifetime management to someone else. ASP.NET Core for example disposes all scoped and transient services (through middleware). Again though, no call to `SaveChanges`, no changes to roll back